# Confused about using `Either` during function call and Multiple use of `Right`

Tags: haskell

#### Here is the first function

Takes a list of Bools converts it to a number after checking for parity

```
ePbs2i :: [Bool] -> Int
ePbs2i bs | parity bs = bitstring2int bs
```

`ePbs2i [True, True]` gives 3

`

#### Here is the second one using `either`

```hs
ePbs2iE :: Error [Bool]          -> Error Int
ePbs2iE    (Left msg)             = Left msg
ePbs2iE    (Right bs) | parity bs = Right (bitstring2int bs)
                      | otherwise = Left "input has odd parity"
```

this is from my professors result sheet. Firstly I don't understand how you can just put a variable `msg` randomly and what it is doing. secondly why is there so many Lefts. Shouldn't the `otherwise` cover everything.  Why is `Right` needed on both the input and the function `bitstring2int bs`

it compiles everything seems ok but as soon as I try   `*Filename> ePbs2iE [True, True]` I get this error.

```
*Filename> ePbs2iE [True, True]

<interactive>:69:9: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Bool]’ with ‘Either String [Bool]’
      Expected type: Error [Bool]
        Actual type: [Bool]
    • In the first argument of ‘ePbs2iE’, namely ‘[True, True]’
      In the expression: ePbs2iE [True, True]
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = ePbs2iE [True, True]
```

I have tried and tried looking at different books or sites. If anyone can link me to a source that also answers this that would be great as that would be a good source for other problems. Also I feel like this covers another topic other than just `Either`

Comment: `Error [Bool]` and `[Bool]` are different types. What makes you think that you can call `ePbs2iE` with a `[Bool]`?

Comment: You can use `msg` because it will be bound if you could match the input with `Left msg` - say you do `ePbs2iE (Left "hey")` then this first pattern will match and `msg` will be `"hey"` in the expressin `Left msg` (right side) - so basically you give the same error back (but this time as a value of `Error Int` instead of the `Error [Bool]` on the left side

Comment: the `| otherwise` is a guard for the second pattern match `(Right bs)` - you will only ever encounter this point when you give some `Right ...` to `ePbs2iE`

Comment: why is `Right` needed? Left of the `=` it is a pattern and right of it you need it as the result of your function needs to be an `Error Int` and it seems that this means either `Left ...` or `Right ...`

Comment: @Brian Wellll... Brian that would be my inexperience. How do I do the call then with`Error [Bool]`

Comment: @confused_oblomov for example with `ePbs2iE (Right [True, True])`

Answer (score 0):

This question raises some interesting differences between Haskell and other languages. It's hard to work out from the question what you are and are not clear on, so I'll try to explain the code as best I can.

First off, *why* use `Either`?

What happens if you pass a value with odd parity to `ePbs2i`?

You'll get an error. What's worse, the error will throw at runtime, and functions that call `ePbs2i` won't see it coming.

This is known as a *partial function* - a function that is not defined for all its possible inputs, and it's something we try to avoid in Haskell.

Enter the `Either` type. `Either` is defined as:

```hs
data  Either a b  =  Left a | Right b
```

i.e. it can hold *either* a value of `a`, *or* of `b`. this is used for indicating failed computations and other errors. By convention, a successful result is indicated by `Right` and a failure by `Left`.

`Error a` in this code is just the same as `Either String a`.

We could use this as follows:

```hs
ePbs2iE1 :: [Bool] -> Either String Int
ePbs2iE1 bs
    | parity bs = Right (bitstring2int bs)
    | otherwise = Left "input has odd parity"
```

This means:

*"If the parity check succeeds, return a `Right` carrying the bitstring. If it fails, return a `Left` with an error message."*

Now the caller is forced to handle the error case. The bitstring can only be gotten at using a pattern match:

```hs
case ePbs2iE1 bits of
    Left int -> doSomeThingWithInt int
    Right msg -> reportError msg
```

The pattern match *binds* the variables `int` and `msg`, so `int` can be used as a variable on the right of the `Left int` arrow, and `msg` on the right of the `Right msg`, but not vice versa.

We have now achieved a *total function* - a function which is defined on all it's inputs.

But the function `ePbs2iE` goes a step further. As well as *returning* a value of type `Either Int`, it also *takes* a value of type `Either [Bool]`. In other words, `ePbs2iE` expects that the computation producing the incoming `[Bool]` may *itself* fail, and it is therefore prepared to handle the failure.

So `ePbs2iE` works as follows:

- *First, pattern match on the incoming `Either [Bool]` (The first `Left`/`Right`, at the beginning of the lines).*

  - *If it is `Left`, i.e. an error condition carrying an error message, pass that through.*
  - *If it receives a `Right` indicating success, then:*

    - *Bind the `[Bool]` to `bs`, and check parity.*
    - *If even, return success (`Right`) with an integer.*
    - *If odd, fail with `Left` carrying an error message.*

So the left-hand `Right`/`Left` are pattern-matching the incoming data, and the right-hand ones are specifying the output.

Of course, since the type of `ePbs2iE`'s argument has now changed from `[Bool]` to `Either String [Bool]`, you can't pass it a `[Bool]` anymore. The GHC error message says as much, once you learn to read it:

```
  • Couldn't match type ‘[Bool]’ with ‘Either String [Bool]’
      Expected type: Error [Bool]
        Actual type: [Bool]
```

To use this function, just wrap the argument in a `Right`, to indicate a valid value, like so: `ePbs2iE (Right [True, True])`.

As you learn more Haskell, I'm sure you will learn about a more elegant solution for chaining `Either` values together: the [`Either` (or `Error`) monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/category-extras-0.52.0/docs/Control-Monad-Either.html).

Happy Haskelling!